# Factoring expression completely

Tags: factoring

Can some one tell me if I got this right? Not fishing for the real answer if I got it wrong, just need to know if I did it right or need to try again. The book I'm working through for practice only has answers to odd numbered problems.

Factor Completely:

Q. 8a^2 - 2b^2

My Answer: 2(2a + b)(2a - b)

Comment: Alright, good. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math rather than programmming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely correct, here are the steps:

```
2(4a^2-b^2)

2((2a)^2 - b^2)

2(2a-b)(2a+b)
```

This is most likely how you must have been factorised.